# how to add another std object inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

I am making an array of std objects in CodeIgniter

```
$result1 = $this->db->query($query1)->result();
```

and I am getting the following result

**Result**

```
Array
   (
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [message_id] => 10
        [sender] => 22
        [receiver] => 24
        [message] => hello atif
        [sent_date] => 02-09-2016
        [sent_time] => 10:12:15am
    )  
 }
```

Now I want to add one more key after `[sent_time]` for example `[anotherKey] => Another Value` string how do I do that?

Comment: `$result1[0]->anotherkey = 'string';`?

Comment: the index is dynamic

Comment: i dont know how many indexes will come, they are depend on data

Comment: So do a foreach / while / loop of some kind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
foreach($result1 as $key=>$value)
{
    $result1[$key]->anotherKey = "Another value";

    $anotherKey = "anotherKey";
    //To apply dynamic value 
    $result1[$key]->$anotherKey = "Another value";
}
```

Comment: @mohsinali you're welcome, great to see that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend object like this:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->anotherKey = "Another Value";
```

Or in loop:

```
foreach ($stdClass as $key => $value) {
    $stdClass[$key]->anotherKey = "Another Value";
}
```

Comment: how can i do in foreach dynamically can you please show how i do that

Comment: Check my answer for loop one.